# React - Connect into analytics reporting API

Tags: reactjs, analytics

I'm trying to connect to the analytics reporting API in my react project, and I'm having some troubles with it. I checked this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started?hl=es where google provides a Quickstart but I'm not being able to reproduce it on React. Could someone please help me??

I tried using react-gapi but I couldn't get through the authentication with OAuth 2...